# Why does tar report not enough disk space when there is plenty of it left?

Tags: tar, disk-usage, ntfs

On a Ubuntu 14.04 system I tried to extract a tar archive:

```
/media/ntfs-drive/target-dir$ tar --extract -v --file ../source-dir/data.tar
```

After extracting some of the files, tar reports that there was not enough disk space left, while in reality there is plenty of it. Here is the output of `df -m` for the relevant device showing that around 86 GByte of free space are left:

```
/dev/sdb5         226966  139075     87892   62% /media/ntfs-drive
```

Also, only 2% of the drive's Inodes are used as `df -i` shows:

```
/dev/sdb5      91114956  1086160 90028796    2% /media/ntfs-drive
```

Some more information that might be of relevance:

- Both the source and the target dir are located on the same NTFS drive
- The archive `data.tar` contains a large number of small files
- My root partition is nearly full (1,4 GByte free)
- `mount` says that the relevant drive has been mounted with options `rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096`

What could be the reason for tar's error message and how can I solve this problem?

**Update**

It seems that this is not really a tar problem, as the system reports the disk to be full after the failed tar extraction. E.g.

```
touch /media/ntfs-disk/test
```

fails with the error that there is not enough space left. However, as I've described above, there is plenty of disk space and Inodes left according to `df`. Are there any hidden temporary files that are not seen by `df`?

**Update 2**

I realized that I can change and increase files on the disk but that I cannot create new files. I'v read [here](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs_vs_fat.htm) that NTFS supports over 4 billion files per volume. Currently my disk contains about 1 million files. But is there another limit on the number of files?

Comment: I would suspect NTFS-related problem. I's not native FS... Is there anything in `dmesg(8)` ? If you reboot in windows and force check of the disk, does the situation change? Only other reason might be `quota(8)` but I'm not sure how it would be handled in NTFS...

Comment: @MatijaNalis I ran `chkdsk` under Windows which revealed that there were a lot of filenames containing `:`, which is an illegal character under Windows. After running `chkdsk` I could create files again. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

GNU tar uses `$TMPDIR` for deciding where to write extended header information.  You might try setting `TMPDIR` to point to a writable location on your large drive.

Comment: Thanks for your answert. Currently I cannot verify if this solves the problem as the system now reports the disk to be full, see my edit.